# ADT update to 22.6.2 failed on Eclipse Helios Service Release 2

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-adt

Going to `Help -> Install New Software -> already installed?`

Clicked `Android Development Tools -> Update`.

Update failed with the following error trace ----

```
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
Software being installed: Android Development Tools 22.6.2.v201403212031-1085508 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 22.6.2.v201403212031-1085508)
Software currently installed: Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers 1.3.2.20110301-1807 (epp.package.jee 1.3.2.20110301-1807)
Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
Eclipse Preferences Mechanism 3.4.2.v20120111-2020 (org.eclipse.equinox.preferences 3.4.2.v20120111-2020)
Eclipse Preferences Mechanism 3.3.0.v20100503 (org.eclipse.equinox.preferences 3.3.0.v20100503)
Eclipse Preferences Mechanism 3.4.1.R37x_v20110725 (org.eclipse.equinox.preferences 3.4.1.R37x_v20110725)
Eclipse Preferences Mechanism 3.4.0.v20110502 (org.eclipse.equinox.preferences 3.4.0.v20110502)
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: Android Development Tools 22.6.2.v201403212031-1085508 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 22.6.2.v201403212031-1085508)
To: org.eclipse.core.runtime 3.7.0
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers 1.3.2.20110301-1807 (epp.package.jee 1.3.2.20110301-1807)
To: org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.feature.feature.group [1.3.2.20110301-1807]
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: Core Runtime 3.7.0.v20110110 (org.eclipse.core.runtime 3.7.0.v20110110)
To: bundle org.eclipse.equinox.preferences [3.4.0,4.0.0)
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: Java EE IDE Feature 1.3.2.20110301-1807 (org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.feature.feature.group 1.3.2.20110301-1807)
To: org.eclipse.platform.feature.group [3.6.2.r362_v20110210-9gF78Gs1FrIGnHDHWkEcopoN8AmxeZflGDGKQi]
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: Eclipse Platform 3.6.2.r362_v20110210-9gF78Gs1FrIGnHDHWkEcopoN8AmxeZflGDGKQi (org.eclipse.platform.feature.group 3.6.2.r362_v20110210-9gF78Gs1FrIGnHDHWkEcopoN8AmxeZflGDGKQi)
To: org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group [3.6.2.r362_v20101104-9SAxFMKFkSAqi8axkv1ZjegmiBLY]
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: Eclipse RCP 3.6.2.r362_v20101104-9SAxFMKFkSAqi8axkv1ZjegmiBLY (org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group 3.6.2.r362_v20101104-9SAxFMKFkSAqi8axkv1ZjegmiBLY)
To: org.eclipse.equinox.preferences [3.3.0.v20100503]
```

Further looking at the above error trace there is a thought that it has a dependency on `Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers` at first place so if I try to update the `Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers` with the same procedure, it takes longer to process the update and then failed with the following error trace----

```
An internal error occurred during: "Install download2".
Comparison method violates its general contract!
```

I have now spent hours to have my ADT update get done but with no means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was that `Helios Service Release 2` wasn't compatible with the *latest ADT version*.

I first downloaded the old release of ADT using the following URL -

http://dl.google.com/android/ADT-22.3.0.zip

Then choosing "Install New Software", "Add Site", "Archive" that I downloaded above.

Worked perfectly well.