# Issue in Updating ADT from 22 to 23

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, adt

Hello friends i update adt 22 to 23 version but when i put http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/  as a installing new ADT see below images for that[image]

When i click "NEXT" button at that time i give error message like as below image

[image]

SO any idea i can i solve this problem ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Update eclipse with Android Development tools 23](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24437564/update-eclipse-with-android-development-tools-23)

Comment: got the same problem n i was unable to solve it so downloaded new ADT bundle

Comment: possible duplicate of [This Android SDK requires Android Developer Toolkit version 23.0.0 or above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24525595/this-android-sdk-requires-android-developer-toolkit-version-23-0-0-or-above)

Answer (score 0):

Visit the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24525595/this-android-sdk-requires-android-developer-toolkit-version-23-0-0-or-above/24526765#24526765) it has the complete solution given by me there itself

Please do not post duplicate questions from next time